# Upgrading to SSD on acer aspire x3960

Tags: boot, ssd

I'm quite new to ubuntu and Linux in general, so if anyone mentions any fancy words I will probably not understand, but I'll do my best to research them. Thanks

Specs:
Mobo: Acer x3960 (Bios: P01-A3) (New CMOS battery)
Ram: 3*2gb
CPU: Intel i5-2300
GPU: NVIDIA GT640 (Asus)
New SSD: Samsung 870 EVO 250gb

I've dug up and old Acer Aspire x3960 hoping to install ubuntu on it to use it as a home server. I knew that I would probably want to swap out the old HDD which was already installed, but before buying anything I wanted to make sure the system worked. Installing Ubuntu on the HDD went smoothly with no problems, therefore I bought an Samsung 870 EVO 250gb SSD.

I Connected the SSD to the same connectors as the old HDD and plugged in my USB drive containing the ubuntu installer which I also used when testing the original system.

When I turned on the system the ubuntu installer booted and I began installing. I chose most of the basic settings, and selected the new SSD as the system drive. When I got "Installation Complete" I was prompted to remove the USB and press enter to reboot, which I did.

To my surprise Intel Boot Agent booted, which was weird because it was last in my boot sequence. And in the BIOS I was not able to see the SSD at all. I then searched for a fix on google and found that many people seemed to be able to change "Boot Mode" from UEFI to LEGACY, but after searching the very limited bios for a while I did not find the option. I did however find the "Sata Mode" option where I could choose between "Native IDE", "RAID" or "AHCI", the setting defaulted to "AHCI". Changing the setting to "IDE" or "RAID" made it so that I could see the SSD in the bios and format and install ubuntu on it in the Ubuntu Installer. And after I rebooted the system it would boot from the SSD, but I get an error that it cant read the files.

---

I've tried to update the BIOS, but as most guides show you how to do so from inside the OS I believe I would need to use Dos or DosTool which I do not know how to use at all.

Any comments will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need AHCI, do not even try others. Your system is new enough to be UEFI, but older and early UEFI. Many UEFI will read an update file directly from a FAT32 partition or flash drive. I make my ESP larger, and use that with my motherboard based desktop systems. I also had to update SSD firmware. Samsung has a Windows tool Magician.But Samsung did have a downloadable ISO for my new NVMe based SSD. Not sure now what other versions have ISO. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/

Comment: Is the new SSD a 2.5 inch SATA drive that goes into the same slot as the old HDD, or is it an NVMe type m.2 drive? Some old UEFI do not boot from NVMe drives.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but will attempt to reformat my USB drive to FAT32 and transfer the "P01-B0.2M" file from the bios update file I got from acer's support site. https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3496?b=1.

Comment: Also yes, the new SSD I got is a 2.5 inch SATA drive, it's plugged into the exact same connectors as the old HDD. https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/870-evo-sata-2-5-ssd-250gb-mz-77e250b-am/

Comment: I tried switching the sata cable again and switching to AHCI, and now it seems to work, but if i unplugg the psu the ssd is not seen untill i switch my sata power cable(my psu has two). Really wierd. Im trying to find some other way to power the ssd, maybe a usb to sata power cable, but i think i have fixed the first issue. Thanks!